# Is "Website Building" is right term?

Tags: differences

I have a website which I saw the SEO & Web Design & Development Videos. To short the title, I use "Website Building & SEO Videos Collection". But I am not sure "Website Building" is the right term? Is it correct word for "Web Design & Development"?

Comment: Yes, that’s perfectly reasonable.

Comment: It should be ***video*** *collection* (singular).

Answer (score 1):

Seems the perfect word for it, as it is a combination of 'Web Designing' and 'Web Developing' while also including other things related to it. I see it used often as a way to describe doing both.

If you're specifically talking about code (markup and and programming), you might as well use 'Coding a website' as building a website may also mean using a drag-and-drop tool of some sort.